# Игнорирование ввода при нажатии на кнопку Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

**Добрый день**. 
Имеется сцена, canvas и кнопка(в canvas), на ЛКМ мой персонаж стреляет из оружия. Каким способом можно сделать игнорирование нажатия ЛКМ при стрельбе, если курсор находится на кнопке. Т.е при нажатии на кнопку у меня происходит 2 действия: стрельба и функция клика по кнопке, как в такой ситуации отключить стрельбу. 
Заранее спасибо)

Comment: [Посмотри в эту сторону](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseEnter.html) Как уже ответили, OnMouseEnter и т.д.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

можешь создать

```
bool FireBlocked
```

и при стрельбе проверять на него.

Ну и, собственно, присваивать true в него во время нажимания на кнопку, и фалс на отжатии.

Если же это игрушка только для компьютера -- советую отлавливать и блочить по `onmouseenter()` и разблокировать по `onmouseexit()` твоей кнопки

Comment: Спасибо, переделал)